# TcxPopUpEdit with TcxTreeList

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-xe2, treelist

I am working on one project where in the main from I have to use a `TcxPopUpEdit` Control to show `PopupList` for each node in the `TcxTreeList` Control.

I am bit new in Delphi.

For Now I am able to show the Popup edit control in the `TcxTreeList` for each Item.

Now the problem is I want to get the selected `popupedit` control from the `Treelist`
and also want to show Some text in the `PopupEdit` control for each `PopupEdit` control in the `Treelist` on Selection of the node.

Can anyone Help me to get the result as desired?

Any type of help can be appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution is to set code in the PropertiesCloseUp.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cxTreeList1: TcxTreeList;
    cxTreeList1Column1: TcxTreeListColumn;
    cxTreeList1Column2: TcxTreeListColumn;
    cxPopupEdit1: TcxPopupEdit;
    procedure cxPopupEdit1PropertiesCloseUp(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.cxPopupEdit1PropertiesCloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if self.cxTreeList1.SelectionCount>0 then
  begin
    self.cxPopupEdit1.Text:= self.cxTreeList1.Selections[0].Values[cxTreeList1Column2.ItemIndex];
  end;
end;
```

For Listbox as popupcontrol in a property 'PopupEdit' of a TcxTreelistColumn:

```
procedure TForm1.cxTreeList1Column2PropertiesCloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if self.cxListBox1.ItemIndex<>-1 then
  begin
    self.cxTreeList1.FocusedNode.Texts[self.cxTreeList1.FocusedColumn.ItemIndex]:=  self.cxListBox1.Items.Strings[self.cxListBox1.ItemIndex];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But, I am showing `popupedit` control for each node in the `TcxTreeList`. Where I have defined the Property of the Column as `PopUpEdit` so for that It is not working as desired

Comment: Did you set the property popupcontrol from the TcxTreeListColumn?

Comment: I've set some new code for closeup in the tcxTreeListColumn

Comment: Ohh, Means it just have to set the value of the node. That's It.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I am facing one more problem regarding the Popup edit in `TcxTreeList` that when I am pressing any key on the treelist control the popup edit gets activated. On the form if I clicked any where I get the Popup for the last selected node.
Can you please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: In my example I've set the cxListBox1 into the popupcontrol as the popupEdit properties of the tcxtreelistcolumn. also set the cxlistbox1.visible to false. The cxlistbox1 popup when I edit the tcxtreelistcolumn.